# Magento Bundle with only one product available is impossible to buy

Tags: product, magento-1.9, bundled-product, bug, addtocart

**Magento 1.9.0.1** with **RWD** template

I have a **Bundle product**, Fruit Box.
I have three **"real" product**: watermelon, type1 melon and type2 melon.

In a Fruit Box i can add **2 single product**, a watermelon and a type of melon. A simple box with two "hole".

I have only one type of Watermelon, so in the product page of bundle i haven't a radio input for this product, because is a mandatory product to have in the Fruit Box.

But i have two type of melons, type1 and type2. So in the bundle i see two radio inputs (selection is mandatory), for selecting which type of melon i can have in the Fruit Box.

Now melon type2 is out of stock.

In the product page of bundle now i see two row: one with the obvious watermelon and one with remained (type1) melon. In both rows **i have no radio inputs**, because obviously there is no longer a choice between products.

Now, when i click to "add to cart" a **notice** tell me that... **i have to select a choice/option**!

And so it is impossible to buy this bundle Fruit Box.

I see the code in `magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml` but i can't figure out where is the problem.

I think is related to the **"if"** inside the **foreach** that generate the radio inputs...

It seems that Magento still expects a radio input with a "**checked**" state... but we have no radio inputs here...

Can someone help me to find the problem? **Thanks!**

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Any info on this? Did you solve it and if so, how? Please add your solution as comment and accept it to help future readers and to increase the quality of this platform. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to inactivity from OP.

Comment: Why closing? I have not found any real solution in case of use of an radio inputs. To make it works now i use dropdown, so users must select a choice.
I have not tested it with Magento 1.9.1.0.
But no one have said that he have the same problem... So i don't know if it is a real bug or a problem in my configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now the only solution for me is to not use radio buttons in the bundle products choice.
Using **dropdowns** users action are required, and all is working great.